# Anatomically Correct Ninki Nanka

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)
[image]

the [Ninki Nanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninki_Nanka) is a mythical creature residing in West Africa which is commonly characterized as:

- being around 30 ft long
- having a long neck similar to a giraffe
- having crocodile-like scales
- having three horns with one at the center of its head (optional)
- having a crocodile-like body
- mostly residing in muddy areas (optional)

Given these characteristics, what species could the Ninki Nanka have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to such a creature?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: How long is the neck? How big are the horns? Is it just a crocodile with a longer neck and ornaments?

Comment: VTC: make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others!

Answer (score 5):

**Plesiosaur.**

[image]

It's no stretch to say these guys laid their eggs on the beach like turtles. So they had some slight degree of movement on the land. Over millions of years some of them adapted to like in rivers rather than the ocean, and sometimes crawl between smaller bodies of water. Hence their flipper adapted to be flipper-feet.